# Why can't I simulate this circuit?

Tags: voltage, rectifier, voltage-doubler

I'm trying to simulate a basic voltage-doubling rectifier circuit:

[image: CircuitLab Schematic 5e96r8vdr52n]

But my time graph looks like this:
[image: Time vs voltage graph]

Is there something wrong with my circuit? Am I using the simulator wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your plot is what you get if you run a simulation with the default timestep of 0.1 seconds, which corresponds to 5 cycles of your AC source. This will not give a result correlating to the effect of the AC on your circuit.

You need to run the simulation with a time step significantly less than the period of the AC voltage source in order for it to have any correlation to the behaviour under AC.

With a timestep of 0.001 seconds, you get twenty simulation steps per AC cycle and a result looking like:

[image]